# How to order folders by their content size in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

How do I get folders to order by their content size in Windows Vista?

Comment: Just a warning: it can take a long time to recursively get the size of all subfolders, and this can really slow down your computer.

Comment: @MatthewTalbert, yes and that is one of the excuses I’ve heard of why Microsoft doesn’t include a built-in column for this, but that’s why you set something like that to off by default and allow the user to enable it instead of just preventing it altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Windows Explorer doesn't allow to sort files by folder size, all is not lost.

Meet **[Folder Size Browser](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/foldersizebrowser/)**, a nifty little utility that does what it says on the tin.

i can't vouch for Vista but since it works in Windows 7, it should do so in Vista.

[image]

*Folder Size Browser is free and portable.*

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, in default Explorer, there is no way to order by the size of a folder.

I have not done it in years, but for XP I used this [free addon](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/foldersize.htm), but I have no idea if it is still compatible and works with Vista.

Comment: Foldersize doesn't work with Vista, and support for Vista will not happen, according to the devolpers blog: http://foldersize.blogspot.com/2009/02/closer-to-25.html

Answer (score 1):

For viewing disk usage I prefer Steffen Gerlach's [Scanner](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/), for its innovative and visual pie display:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Total commander](http://ghisler.com/) has this built in

- menu Configuration -> Options, go to Display settings and for Sorting Directories select "Like files"
- make sure you are showing full info (menu Show -> Full)
- click on Size column button (default sorts from biggest to smallest, click again to reverse it)
- press Alt+Shift+Enter and wait for the directories to be scanned, depending on the size it could take a while

Result will be all directories showing cumulative size of all the files in them (including in all subdirectories)

Comment: Looks like it's still a Windows 3.1 application. Works exactly how you described in Windows 7 though!

Answer (score 0):

Something perhaps more powerful than a folder size utility is [Space Sniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/index.html).  It's free; it works in Windows 7, so presumably works in Vista too.  It allows you to quckly drill down to large files and folders.

[image]